# Does CBSA/ASFC's restriction on importing mattresses apply to camping mattresses?

Tags: canada, regulations

From the [CBSA/ASFC Prohibited Goods list](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/pub/bsf5056-eng.html#s5x9):

> You cannot import used or second-hand mattresses into Canada unless you have a certificate that verifies the mattresses have been cleaned and fumigated in the country of export. A letter, or any other document that clearly demonstrates that this requirement has been met, is acceptable if it is signed by a person qualified in cleaning and fumigating.

If I go hiking in Canada, I would like to bring my camping mattress.  Does the restriction on importing mattresses apply to strictly outdoor camping mattresses?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know the answer, but the following information may help someone who does: Is your "camping mattress" a bedroll/mattress or a backpacking style sleeping pad?

Comment: It's a backpacking style sleeping pad, quite thin.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at more official description of what is actually prohibited on a different page from [Canadian Customs](http://www.canadiancustoms.org/bringing-a-used-mattress-to-canada/), so unless your camping pad can be used as a household item and fits into one of these categories:

> - 9806.00.00 – Bequests, meaning that the mattress was given to you after someone passed away.
> - 9807.00.00 – Settlers’ effects, so if you are immigrating to Canada you can bring your mattress without having it fumigated.
> - 9808.00.00 -Customs Privileges for Diplomatic Missions, Consular Posts, and International Organizations. So if you are working for another country as part of a diplomatic mission or an international organization, you might not have to get your mattress fumigated.
> - 9809.00.00 -Articles for the use of the Governor General.
> - 9810.00.00 -Goods imported by designated foreign countries, military service agencies and institutions.

you should not have to have it cleaned and fumigated.  Though periodic cleaning might be a good a idea anyway.